# jquery .hide() function - Hide mobile, Display Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'll try my best to set up my scenario so that you can understand my question.

My site is currently taking advantage of css media queries to span between screen resolutions. I have a main drilldown menu that can not be hidden on page load, otherwise the menu will not correctly calculate it's height, and will not display properly.

As a way to still be able to hide this menu when needed, I have found a workaround that hides the menu, yet still allows the menu to correctly calculate it's height on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide-menu").hide();
    var $drillDown = $("#drilldown");
});
```

This is great for pages that do not require the main menu to be displayed initially on both mobile and desktop resolutions. However, for my product pages this solution will not work. I need the menu to hide on load for mobile resolutions, but also display on load for desktop resolutions. Can anyone think of a solution that will work? I'm stumped. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="drill-down-wrapper hide-menu hide-on-load hide-pd-page">
    <div id="drilldown-breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs skin-colorful"></div>
    <div id="drilldown" class="skin-colorful">
        <!-- #Include virtual="Menu.txt" -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use media queries to hide and show the menus based on screen resolutions.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in the descption. display:none; and display:hidden; are not an option for me. They cause the menu to not correctly calculate it's height. As far as I'm aware, there is no CSS for .hide()

Comment: @AlexRitter hide() is the same as `display: none`

Comment: If you'd like to preserve the height use visibility: hidden;

Comment: Dang it. I meant display:none; and visibility:hidden; are both not an option for me. They both cause the menu to not calculate the correct height. The jQuery hides it after the initial load, and that it why it works, and css does not.

Comment: There are definitely other ways of detecting OS or device but they are much more difficult.  I'd google around and try to find the best option for you.  There SHOULD be a way to accomplish what you're doing with CSS but without a site to inspect I can't really help you.

Comment: You can view the issue live at: http://temp1.yandasmusic.com/1/productid/5688/taylor-310-dreadnought-acoustic-guitar

Answer (score 0):

Rather than jQuery, try using CSS to show/hide elements. You can use the `display` rule to do so. Just as an example:

```
.hide-menu-on-load {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .hide-menu-on-load {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Note: `display: none` removed the element from the flow of the page. `visibility: hidden` keeps the element's flow on the page, yet simply removes it from view

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in the descption. display:none; and display:hidden; are not an option for me. They cause the menu to not correctly calculate it's height.